# React Native multi view in list?

Tags: react-native, slider

Hi everyone I want to design UI like this image.but I don't know to design list like that to get value in seekbar(Slider) all item?Please help me thank a [image]lot !!

Comment: have you checked this? https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-slider

Answer (score 0):

You can check this official react native package [rn-slider](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-slider) Good documentations. you will get the slider there. and for images, you just put them in `flexDirection:'row'` along with the slider component.

[image]

hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: I mean design UI like that..because a lot of item like this in bottom?

Comment: I want to design like list but don't know how to design item?

Comment: whats the problem in designing? each component with different pics will be rendered like that

Comment: I mean help me design item like this.because there are three or four or two slider in one item list?

Comment: yeah, rather make each component in scrollview

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand what exactly you need but if you need to access value on slidebar, you can define a state like SliderValue and pass it to value and onValueChanged props in Slider :

```
render() {
return (
  <View style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: this.state.ColorHolder }]} >

    {/*Text to show slider value*/}
    <Text style={styles.headerText}>Value of slider is : {this.state.sliderValue}</Text>

    {/*Slider with max, min, step and initial value*/}
    <Slider
      maximumValue={100}
      minimumValue={0}
      minimumTrackTintColor="#307ecc"
      maximumTrackTintColor="#000000"
      step={1}
      value={this.state.sliderValue}
      onValueChange={(sliderValue) => this.setState({ sliderValue })}
      style={{ width: 300, height: 40 }}
    />

  </View>
);
```

}

Comment: I mean design UI like that use flatlist or design each item?

Comment: I want to design like list but don't know how to design item?